How is it possible to prevent the display of json files from the browser?
How is it possible to prevent the display of json files present in a folder of an web application from the browser? I have already disabled director listening for that folder, but if I point directly in the URL to the file I can see it from the browser. Web Server is IIS.

I don't do IIS, but are you talking about going to a folder and seeing all the files or something else?  If its this - you should just be able to put a file "index.html" in the folder.

Sorry, let me explain better. if I point directly to the json file from the browser I read it. I would like not to let it show. The index.html file already exists.

You probably can't do this reliably without doing some kind of authentication/cookie/tracking.  Again, I don't do IIS, but I'd be inclined to write a PHP "default" file, then some code to check the downloader is authorized and read and spit out the file through PHP.  At a push you might be able to do something by looking at the browser agent, but thats easy to fake.  Can you make use of "Basic Auth" or something to password protect it?

If the files are needed to display the webpage the browser must somehow get the information (aka read the files), but you can, as mentioned above, create a script so that only the output of the rendered json file is seen by the browser and not the files themselves.
